# UICollectionView changing size when empty

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, nib

I am facing a weird situation where a `UICollectionView` changes size if it is loaded with 0 cells the first time. If it is loaded with more than 0 cells the first time it keeps the correct size. This behaviour doesn't make any sense to me and I don't know how to correct it.

I am using a paginated collection view, similar to what is described [here](http://blog.learningtree.com/paging-with-collection-views-part-1/).

That means that I am setting the cell size to be the same as the collection view's size:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return collectionView.bounds.size;
}
```

Oddly enough I am getting this error message:

```
2016-02-23 14:27:10.574 the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
2016-02-23 14:27:10.574 the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
2016-02-23 14:27:10.575 The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fa90ac86d30>, and it is attached to <UICollectionView: 0x7fa90c84da00; frame = (0 0; 414 150); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fa90ac88450>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fa90ac85b70>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {828, 187}> collection view layout: <UICollectionViewFlowLayout: 0x7fa90ac86d30>.
2016-02-23 14:27:10.575 Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
```

Basically telling me that the cell's height is greater than the collection view's height, which doesn't really make any sense, since I am setting the cell's size to be the same as the collection view.

It seems to me like the collection view is changing its height depending on whether it is empty or not, which doesn't make any sense to me. Does anyone know how I can fix this or have any suggestions on how I can work around it?

**UPDATE:**

It seems like I didn't fully understand the problem when I asked this question. I thought the problem was due to the fact that I didn't have any cells the first time I loaded the collection view. So I thought a simple solution would be to put an empty placeholder cell, while loading the content. Unfortunately, the size of the cell is still screwed up when I reload the data. So the problem seems to be that the size is only correct the first time I load the collection view and on any subsequent reload the size becomes incorrect.

Comment: what about contentinset of uicollectionview?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I found a solution: By setting the `estimatedItemSize` on the layout I get rid of the problem.

```
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = collectionView.bounds.size;
```

**EDIT:** This solution works when the width of the cell fits on the screen. Otherwise the cell will take up as much space as it needs to fully show its content and it will be wider than the screen if the content is too big. Since I have dynamic content, this is not acceptable. This solution might work for someone else in a similar situation, so I am keeping this answer, but I will have to find a better solution.

Comment: This solution seems to have screwed up the width of the cells. They are now too wide instead of too high. So now I need to find a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the resizing of the collection view. It had a constraint to a `UIPageControl` that would disappear when there was 0 or 1 pages. My solution was to set the `hidesForSinglePage` property to `NO` and use a placeholder cell when there is no content.

Another solution would have been to make the constraint to the bottom of the super view rather than to the `UIPageControl`. This way, it would be ok for the page control to disappear. I want the page control to be there at all times, but if you don't, this solution would be the one for you. Alternatively you could have the super view resize based on whether the page control is visible.